# Iphone App changes that require re-submittal

Tags: iphone

I am doing an app with both static and changing information/graphics.  The logo and purpose stay the same, but the graphics and text will change continuously on 1 skin.  Does that matter at all? Feel free to just point me to a link that explains this better. I haven't been able to find it in the iphone devel. guide thus far.

Comment: Does what matter? What is your question?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Are you asking if it's possible to have users customize the look and information displayed in your application without requiring separate applications for each of these looks?

Comment: Some of the information about what is permitted is included in the iOS SDK Developer Agreement required when signing up for the iOS Developer program (you should save a copy before clicking "Agree").  Other parts are in the iTunes Connect user guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the name, icon, default images, or any executable or interpreted code (other than Javascript run in a UIWebView) in an iOS app without re-submittal.  If you want to change any of the above, you will need to (re)submit the app to Apple.

You cannot change the keywords or screenshots used by the App store, but you can update the text description of an app in the App store without resubmitting the app.

But an app can download and change almost all other content in an app, including text, databases, button labels, colors, images, sounds, UI coordinates, Javascript, etc.  There's even an Apple WWDC 2010 video on this data driven app design methodology.  You can also add certain badges to an app's icon at run-time.  Note that if you aren't filtering certain data/web downloads, your app may get/require an Adult rating.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are using Public APIs, it does not matter where you pull content from.  I would recommend having fall-back graphics in your bundle that can be loaded if the external stuff cannot be found.  Other than that, the content is up to you Apple is only trying to make sure the application itself is functional using publicly-available APIs.